# BeautifulSoup: searching for multiple tags

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm currently implementing Beautiful Soup in my application to search through a user's HTML content. How it works is that if the user does not input one of the HTML tags specified, it returns a false value. This works fine when there is only one HTML tag, however I also want this to work for multiple HTML tags. 
Here is my code.

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(userInput, 'html.parser')
if soup.find(['h1','h2']) is None:
   return false
else:
   return true
```

So how I want it to work is that if all elements in the array [h1,h2] are not in the user input, then it will return false. How the code above is functioning is that if the user enters one of the values in the array it will return true.

Is there any way to implement this in Python?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.find` does not work this way. You'll have to call it once per tag:

```
if not any(soup.find(tag) for tag in ('h1', 'h2')):
    # if inputted HTML does not contain h1 or h2 tags
```

You can of course use any logic you need. If you want to enforce that both `h1` and `h2` tags exist, use

```
if not all(soup.find(tag) for tag in ('h1', 'h2'))
```

Comment: I was looking to enforce that both the tags existed. Thanks a lot man! I had tried if not all but was unable to get the for loop correct.